# I am having an error that I do not understand.

Tags: c++

I am getting error saying i am missing a terminating  and not to mention that i am missing an ';" at grid[bl][cl]=(char)'\';

```
int bl= rand()%MAXROWS;
int cl= rand()%MAXCOL;
int dir = rand()%2;
if(dir==0){
    grid[bl][cl]= (char) '\';

}
else
    grid[bl][cl]='/';
```

Comment: '\' needs to be escaped to '\\'

Answer (score 3):

The backslash `\` character actually escapes the following `'` character, so you are leftover with an unclosed literal. You can fix it by writing

```
grid[bl][cl]= (char) '\\';
                   // ^
```

The backslash character is used to escape itself.